# ERROR: ' ' device did not show up after 30 seconds

Tags: linux, arch-linux

When installing archlinux 2019.04.01 I get

```
losetup /run/archiso/bootmnt/arch/x86_64/airootfs.sfs:failed to set up loop device: No such file or directory
```

**some useless rows here**

```
Mounting ' ' to /run/archiso/sfs/rootfs

ERROR: ' ' device did not show up after 30 seconds
```

Flash drive name is ARCH_201904 ,so I don't know whats is problem, but ERROR I see ' ',and in other asks here some way like /dev/disk/by-label

I used dd to make a bootable flash drive.

Thanks for answers...